Set webform composite rows to another field's value
I have a field to enter a number and then a composite set of fields. Is there a way to set the number of rows in the composite to be the number entered in that separate field? Preferably, it would update the number of rows immediately when the other field's value is updated. But splitting between two pages would also be ok.
